# Problem with tabbing through 4 text input boxes in action script 3

Tags: actionscript-3, forms, flash-cs3, tabbing

I hope someone has the patience to look at this.....

I have a flash form and need to set a tabbing order for the four textinput boxes in the form.

**The four boxes are named:**

```
name_txt
surname_txt
email_txt
phone_txt
```

Each box is an instance of a generic textinput box component

At the moment when a use is focussed on name_txt and hits tab the focus jumps to email_txt

hit tab again and focus disappears altogether.

Focus on surname_txt then hit tab and focus jumps to phone_txt - tab again focus disappears.

The textinput fields are nest within a movie clip which in turn is nested in a movie clip which on the main stage.

any clues as to how to how to set the tabbing order would be greatly appreciated

A million thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to set the tabIndex property of your textfields secuentially... I suggest you read the documentation as it is quite unique in AS3:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS3LCR/Flash_10.0/flash/display/InteractiveObject.html#tabIndex